# How to filter outliers in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to filter outliers in a mySQL dataset without success.  I'd like to calculate an average of a column, broken down by date, excluding values that fall outside 2 standard deviations from the mean.

an example table:

```
+---------------------+----------+
|      date_time      | duration |
+---------------------|----------+
| 2015-01-01 00:01:00 |    1     |
| 2015-01-01 00:02:00 |    2     |
| 2015-01-01 00:02:20 |    23    |
| 2015-01-01 00:03:10 |    3     |
| 2015-01-02 00:01:00 |    3     |
| 2015-01-02 00:02:00 |    4     |
| 2015-01-02 00:02:20 |    52    |
| 2015-01-02 00:03:10 |    5     |   ...
```

How can I get an average of the duration column excluding the outliers "23" and "52" which are well outside of 2 standard deviations from the mean?

I'd like to get a result like:

```
+------------+---------+
|   date     | average |
+------------+---------|
| 2015-01-01 |    2    |
| 2015-02-01 |    4    |
```

I think I need 2 separate queries combined with a join, or a sub query, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT AVG(value)
FROM yourtable yt
INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(value) AS avrg, STDDEV(value) AS stdv
FROM your table ) ilv
ON yt.value BETWEEN avrg-2*stdv AND avrg+2*stdv
```

I can't give you an answer like your example as your example doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry - I had a typo in the example numbers.  Basically I want an average of the duration column, grouped by day, excluding the outliers.  So on 2015-01-01, the average should be (1+2+3)/3 = 2 (excluding 23).  And on 2015-02-01, the average should be (3+4+5)/3 = 4 (excluding 52).  Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: So cast the date_time column to a date (marginally faster than date_format) and group by it.